# Error occurs while ASCII85 decoding and FlateDecoding in a row

Tags: c#, parsing, pdf, decoding

I have used the following code to decode text stream in pdf. There are instances where the stream needs to be decoded by 2 filters. 
<< /Length 2348 /Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ] >>
I decode the stream first by ASCII85Decode and then Flatedecode. For some cases, flatedecoded final result becomes null. Any idea on the issue?

```
    public byte[] decode(byte[] encodedInput)
    {
        bool strict = false;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedInput);
        InflaterInputStream zip = new InflaterInputStream(stream);
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[strict ? 4092 : 1];
        try
        {
            int n;
            while ((n = zip.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(b, 0, n);
            }
            zip.Close();
            output.Close();
            return (output.ToArray());
        }
        catch
        {
            if (strict)
                return null;
            return (output.ToArray());
        }
    }

//ASCII85Decode

class ASCII85 : IASCII85
{
    /// <summary>
 /// Prefix mark that identifies an encoded ASCII85 string, traditionally 
'<~'
 /// </summary>
    public string PrefixMark = "<~";
    /// <summary>
    /// Suffix mark that identifies an encoded ASCII85 string, 
traditionally '~>'
    /// </summary>
    public string SuffixMark = "~>";
    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum line length for encoded ASCII85 string; 
    /// set to zero for one unbroken line.
    /// </summary>
    public int LineLength = 75;
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the Prefix and Suffix marks when encoding, and enforce their 
presence for decoding
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnforceMarks = true;

    private const int _asciiOffset = 33;
    private byte[] _encodedBlock = new byte[5];
    private byte[] _decodedBlock = new byte[4];
    private uint _tuple = 0;
    private int _linePos = 0;
    private uint[] pow85 = { 85 * 85 * 85 * 85, 85 * 85 * 85, 85 * 85, 85, 
1 };

    /// <summary>
    /// Decodes an ASCII85 encoded string into the original binary data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputString">ASCII85 encoded string</param>
    /// <returns>byte array of decoded binary data</returns>
    public byte[] decode(string inputString)
    {
        if (EnforceMarks)
        {
            bool x = !inputString.StartsWith(PrefixMark);
            bool y = !inputString.EndsWith(SuffixMark);
            bool a = !inputString.StartsWith(PrefixMark) && 
!inputString.EndsWith(SuffixMark);             
            if (a)
            {
                throw new Exception("ASCII85 encoded data should begin with 
'" + PrefixMark +
                    "' and end with '" + SuffixMark + "'");
            }
        }
        if (inputString.StartsWith("<~"))
        {
            inputString = inputString.Substring(PrefixMark.Length);
        }
        if (inputString.EndsWith("~>"))
        {
            inputString = inputString.Substring(0, inputString.Length - 
SuffixMark.Length);
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        int count = 0;
        bool processChar = false;

        foreach (char c in inputString)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'z':
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("The character 'z' is invalid 
inside an ASCII85 block.");
                    }
                    _decodedBlock[0] = 0;
                    _decodedBlock[1] = 0;
                    _decodedBlock[2] = 0;
                    _decodedBlock[3] = 0;
                    ms.Write(_decodedBlock, 0, _decodedBlock.Length);
                    processChar = false;
                    break;
                case '\n':
                case '\r':
                case '\t':
                case '\0':
                case '\f':
                case '\b':
                    processChar = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (c < '!' || c > 'u')
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Bad character '" + c + "' 
                    found. ASCII85 only allows characters '!' to 'u'.");
                    }
                    processChar = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (processChar)
            {
                _tuple += ((uint)(c - _asciiOffset) * pow85[count]);
                count++;
                if (count == _encodedBlock.Length)
                {
                    DecodeBlock();
                    ms.Write(_decodedBlock, 0, _decodedBlock.Length);
                    _tuple = 0;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count != 0)
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("The last block of ASCII85 data cannot 
be a single byte.");
            }
            count--;
            _tuple += pow85[count];
            DecodeBlock(count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                ms.WriteByte(_decodedBlock[i]);
            }
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes binary data into a plaintext ASCII85 format string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ba">binary data to encode</param>
    /// <returns>ASCII85 encoded string</returns>
    public string encode(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int)(ba.Length *  
(_encodedBlock.Length / _decodedBlock.Length)));
        _linePos = 0;

        if (EnforceMarks)
        {
            AppendString(sb, PrefixMark);
        }

        int count = 0;
        _tuple = 0;
        foreach (byte b in ba)
        {
            if (count >= _decodedBlock.Length - 1)
            {
                _tuple |= b;
                if (_tuple == 0)
                {
                    AppendChar(sb, 'z');
                }
                else
                {
                    EncodeBlock(sb);
                }
                _tuple = 0;
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _tuple |= (uint)(b << (24 - (count * 8)));
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            EncodeBlock(count + 1, sb);
        }

        if (EnforceMarks)
        {
            AppendString(sb, SuffixMark);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void EncodeBlock(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        EncodeBlock(_encodedBlock.Length, sb);
    }

    private void EncodeBlock(int count, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        for (int i = _encodedBlock.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            _encodedBlock[i] = (byte)((_tuple % 85) + _asciiOffset);
            _tuple /= 85;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            char c = (char)_encodedBlock[i];
            AppendChar(sb, c);
        }

    }

    private void DecodeBlock()
    {
        DecodeBlock(_decodedBlock.Length);
    }

    private void DecodeBlock(int bytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            _decodedBlock[i] = (byte)(_tuple >> 24 - (i * 8));
        }
    }

    private void AppendString(StringBuilder sb, string s)
    {
        if (LineLength > 0 && (_linePos + s.Length > LineLength))
        {
            _linePos = 0;
            sb.Append('\n');
        }
        else
        {
            _linePos += s.Length;
        }
        sb.Append(s);
    }

    private void AppendChar(StringBuilder sb, char c)
    {
        sb.Append(c);
        _linePos++;
        if (LineLength > 0 && (_linePos >= LineLength))
        {
            _linePos = 0;
            sb.Append('\n');
        }
    }

    public string decode(byte[] ba)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a PDF for which the error occurs and your code for ASCII85 processing to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: pdf link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVS3W_vwfiAp1uI6MYyr3QquIpgE2CYn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mkl what is the default value of text Leading parameter(TL)?

Comment: *"the default value of text Leading parameter(TL)"* - if you don't set the leading (**TL** / **TD**), it's *0*.

Comment: @mkl how to detect reading direction of pdf, whether it is top to bottom or bottom to top?

Comment: I'm not aware of a sure indicator for bottom-to-top reading orders.

Comment: is there a way to find reading direction?

Comment: *"is there a way to find reading direction?"* - You might want to make that an actual question, not a mere comment. I myself don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your `InflaterInputStream`, so I used the `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream` instead.

I took all stream contents with `/Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ]` from your example file and tried to decode them in a `String rawStreamChars` like this:

```
ASCII85 ascii85 = new ASCII85();
ascii85.EnforceMarks = false;
byte[] ascii85Decoded = ascii85.decode(rawStreamChars);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ascii85Decoded))
{
    // Remove 2 bytes zlib header
    stream.ReadByte();
    stream.ReadByte();
    using (DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream())
    {
        decompressionStream.CopyTo(result);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetString(result.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

And in each case I got the respective content stream.

Thus, you either

- incorrectly retrieve the stream contents from the stream object; or
- incorrectly use your `ASCII85` class (e.g. by using `EnforceMarks = true`); or
- have an issue in your `decode` method.

Well, or there is some less obvious bug at work.

Comment: It was an implementation problem, I have used the same ASCII85 object for multiple pages of the pdf. Some variables needed to be cleared before decoding again. Now, the code is working. Thank you for the answer.